# How to set pagecontent's height dynamically in pageviewcontroller?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, height

I have a ViewController, that contains some image, labels and empty view. I put my PageViewController into this empty view. The problem is both pagecontents have not static height.

**The question is how to set this emptyView's height to be the same as biggest among this two pagecontents?**

For now I am thinking of sending notification with the height to the main viewcontroller from both pagecontents. And set them from there, but I believe there has to be more elegant solution. At the time I am writing this, there is a static height of 500.

**Second question : is there any way to set view's height depending on it's content**

```
    self.pageviewcontroller.view.frame =
        CGRect(x: 0,
               y: 0,
               width: self.pageContentView.frame.width,
               height: 500)
```

I would like to solve this problem with the answer of the second question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like this:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        self.pageviewcontroller.view.frame =
            CGRect(x: 0,
                   y: 0,
                   width: self.pageContentView.frame.width,
                   height: self.pageContentView.frame.height)
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! knowing viewDidLayotSubviews() solved my problems!